# Get Cosmosdb Container Collection items using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cosmosdb, azure-powershell, az

Team,  I had created new CosmosDB account in Azure portal with a container contains list of collection items. I am able to access Container details in power shell script.

***How to list collection items  or show specific collection item using partition key using power shell script***

**Power shell Script :**

```
  Get-AzResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers" -ApiVersion "2020-03-01" -ResourceGroupName "testRG" -Name "cosmosaccount1/database1/containercollection1"
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use something like a thirdparty module for this. Azure Resource Manager doesnt support that, hence you need to talk to Cosmos DB directly.

https://github.com/PlagueHO/CosmosDB

Answer (score 1):

The Cosmos DB repo has a set of examples to use Powershell: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/tree/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/PowerShellRestApi

Particularly to read Items: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/PowerShellRestApi/PowerShellScripts/ReadItem.ps1

They are all using the REST API to do REST request, in this case, it is an authenticated `GET` to `https://{databaseaccount}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{db-id}/colls/{coll-id}/docs/{id}` (where *databaseaccount* is your account name, *db-id* is the id of your database, *coll-id* is the id of your collection/container, and *id* is your document id). It is also setting the `x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey` header for the partition key.

Comment: Do we have any reference link for "How to Get Cosmos Db document using Querying in REST API". I am trying to do POST verb with Body as JSON to get specific document with sql query but am getting error

Comment: It's on the REST API documents: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/query-documents

Answer (score 1):

Like @4c74356b41 has indicated, you can use the CosmosDB module, which is now part of the [official Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/powershell-samples).

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
```

You can see the available commands with Get-Commands:

```
Import-Module Az
Import-Module -Name CosmosDB
Get-Command -Module CosmosDB
```

**Get all items in a collection**

In order to get all entries inside a container, we use the *Get-CosmosDbDocument* command:

```
$subscription = "SubscriptionName"
$resourceGroupName = "ResourceGroupName"
$accountName = "AzureCosmosDBAccount"
$databaseName = "DatabaseName"
$cosmosContainer = "TargetCosmosDBContainer"

Set-AzContext $subscription
$backOffPolicy = New-CosmosDbBackoffPolicy -MaxRetries 5 -Method Additive -Delay 1000
$cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account $accountName -Database
$databaseName -ResourceGroup $resourceGroupName -BackoffPolicy $backOffPolicy

$documentsPerRequest = 100
$continuationToken = $null
$documents = $null
do {
    $responseHeader = $null
    $getCosmosDbDocumentParameters = @{
        Context = $cosmosDbContext
        CollectionId = $cosmosContainer
        MaxItemCount = $documentsPerRequest
        ResponseHeader = ([ref] $responseHeader)
    }

    if ($continuationToken) {
        $getCosmosDbDocumentParameters.ContinuationToken = $continuationToken
    }

    $documents += Get-CosmosDbDocument @getCosmosDbDocumentParameters
    $continuationToken = Get-CosmosDbContinuationToken -ResponseHeader $responseHeader
} while (-not [System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($continuationToken))
```

Note: There is no apparent limitation on the number of documents that can be retrieved with this command, but it stands to reason that the command will have the API limitation, and this is 4 MB (as [documented here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#per-request-limits)). The value here ($documentsPerRequest = 100) could prove to be either too big or too small, depending on the size of each document. I usually don't use this parameter, but I've mentioned it here in case someone needs it.

**List specific collection item**

To get a specific entry or group of entries from a container, we use the same *Get-CosmosDbDocument* command, in a slightly different way:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.property = 'propertyValue'"
$documents = Get-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId $cosmosContainer -Query $query -QueryEnableCrossPartition $true
```

Note: For brevity I haven't went to the process of getting a continuation token, but if the query will return a result that is larger than 4 MB, then we will only receive the first part of the response. To make sure this does not happen we should add "Query" and "QueryEnableCrossPartition" in the $getCosmosDbDocumentParameters dictionary.